# Why does the radius of orbit increase when a satellite increases it's velocity?

Tags: classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, centripetal-force

Can someone please explain to me why increasing the velocity of a satellite with a rocket booster will change the radius of the orbit rather than the linear velocity of the satellite? If the angular momentum of the satellite earth system is conserved, shouldn't an increase in v lead to a decrease in r?

Comment: I smell the delicate waft of homework. Anyway, V^2 / R = GMm/R^2. And, who says the angular momentum is conserved when you use a rocket booster?

Comment: Speaking about the radius of the orbit, apparently, you refer to a circular orbit. An increase in velocity, in general, does not preserve the shape of the orbit.

Answer (score 1):

The angular momentum is conserved during free flight (no rocket boosters applied). When this is the case, speed and distance are inversely related, as you said.

When speed is increased by firing the rocket boosters at some point in the orbit, it is increased to something other than what it was at that point. This means that angular momentum is *not* conserved during that process. When the rocket fires, speed increases, as does angular momentum. With the increase in angular momentum, the radius at any speed will now be larger.

Note that firing the rockets will in general change the shape of the orbit. This is because the position can not instantaneously change, so the rocket changes the speed at the same position. Therefore, you cannot fire the rocket and just move the ship to a different radius. Instead what happens is the new speed puts it into a transfer orbit, which has a larger eccentricity. If it is desired to settle into a circular orbit at a higher radius, then when you get to that distance you have to fire the rocket again. This again changes the orbit shape, but it reduces the eccentricity.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the future dynamical state of the orbit will depend entirely on the acceleration vector when the thrust is applied.

Simply stating that the velocity of an object in orbit has increased is too vague to describe what the final steady state orbit will look like. Velocity and Acceleration are vectors that have both a direction and magnitude.

Casse 1: Thrust is applied tangentially to the orbit in the same direction as the orbital trajectory. this will result in an increase in angular momentum and an increase in apogee.

Case 2: If the thrust is applied tangentially in the opposite direction of the trajectory, the angular momentum will decrease and the satellite will 'fall' into a lower orbit and the apogee will be lowered.

Case 3: If the thrust is applied normal to the tangential vector directly towards to or away from the Earth, the orbital eccentricity will be changed but the angular momentum remains constant as no torque via tangential acceleration was applied. This will simply result in a change in eccentricity and the apogee or perigee respectively.

Case 4: You apply too much energy via thrust that is directed outward or tangentially. In this case the satellite will spiral away from the Earth and never come back. You will have accelerated the Satellite beyond the escape velocity, and it will have a normal component of velocity that will never fall to zero relative to the Earth. Like the Voyager spacecraft, it will never return and will proceed to the far reaches of space.